# Matrices problem: $AB=B$ and $BA=A$, what is $A^2+B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$, then $A^2+B^2$ would be equal to?

Comment: It's not. Please check again.

Comment: @noam I had figured that out myself before but I'm not getting how the answer is A+B..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}A^2+B^2&=(BA)(BA)+(AB)(AB)\\
&=B(AB)A+A(BA)B\\
&=B(BA)+A(AB)\\
&=BA+AB\\
&=A+B\end{align}$$

Hope the helps.

Answer (score 4):

One may wonder what these conditions mean geometrically.

**Claim.** If $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ then both $A$ and $B$ are projections onto the same subspace $U\subset X$. In particular $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$.

*Proof.* One has $A=BA=ABA=A^2$, and similarly for $B$. It follows that both $A$ and $B$ are projections onto subspaces $U_A$, $U_B\subset X$.

Since $B\restriction U_B$ is the identity map on $U_B$ the condition  $AB=B$ implies that $A\restriction U_B$ is the identity map on $U_B$ as well. This implies $U_A\supset  U_B$, and similarly one proves $U_B\supset U_A\>$.$\quad\square$

On the other hand ${\rm ker}A$ and ${\rm ker}B$ need not coincide, as the example
$$A=\left[\matrix{0&0\cr 0&1\cr}\right],\quad B=\left[\matrix{0&0\cr -1&1\cr}\right]$$
shows.